# Could someone explain to me what the tree traversal is doing here?

Tags: algorithm, ocaml

I am having a hard time understanding the tree_traverse function and what it does, could someone please explain.

(Peek and pop is just from a stack implementation which I made.)

```
type 'a tree = Leaf | Branch of ('a tree * 'a * 'a tree);;

let rec tree_traverse (t,mem,prim,seco) = match t with
  | Leaf ->
    if is_empty mem
    then []
    else tree_traverse (peek mem, pop mem, prim, seco)
  | Branch (l,nd,r) ->
    let mem1 = add (prim(l,r),mem) in
    let mem2 = add (seco(l,r), mem1) in
    nd :: tree_traverse (peek mem2, pop mem2, prim, seco)
```

where an example of a tree is

```
  let t = Branch (Branch(Branch(Leaf,1,Leaf), 2, Leaf), 3,
            Branch (Branch(Leaf,5,Leaf), 6, Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf)))
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What are you trying to accomplish? Also quick sidenotes: Indent your code, don't use tuples as function parameters, and give meaningful names to your variables.

Answer (score 2):

This function implements some sort of the worklist algorithm, it returns a list of nodes in some order that depends on the implementation of `prim` and `seco` functions, as well as `add` and `pop`.

Neither `prim` nor `seco` parameter is changed during the recursion, so the could be removed from the list of parameters. If we will assume the following implementations

```
 let add (x,xs) = x :: xs
 let pop (x::xs) = xs
 let peek (x::xs) = x
 let prim (x,y) = x
 let seco (x,y) = y
 let is_empty = function [] -> true | _ -> false
```

then the `tree_traverse` function will return the list of nodes in the depth-first order.

Given your example and fixing the implementation to the specified above functions, we can now follow the execution of the function:

```
tree_traverse Branch (Branch(Branch(Leaf,1,Leaf), 2, Leaf), 3,
        Branch (Branch(Leaf,5,Leaf), 6, Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf)))
```

doesn't match with the `Leaf` case so we go to the second case and get it deconstructed as

```
 | Branch (l,nd,r)) ->
    (* l is bound to Branch (Branch(Leaf,1,Leaf), 2, Leaf) *)
    (* nd is bound to 3 *)
    (* r is bound to Branch (Branch(Leaf,5,Leaf), 6, Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf)) *)
    let mem1 = add (prim(l,r),mem) in
    let mem2 = add (seco(l,r), mem1) in
    nd :: tree_traverse (peek mem2, pop mem2, prim, seco)
```

we push the left sub-branch `l` to the first stack `mem1`, and push the left and right subbranches to the stack `mem2`. Then we prepend `3` to the result and recurse with into the top of our stack `mem2` while dropping it.

In the next step, we are matching on the top of our second stack, which contains the right branch, namely `Branch (Branch(Leaf,5,Leaf), 6, Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf))`, we land again to the second case, with 
`Branch(Leaf,5,Leaf)` being bound to the `l` variable, and `Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf)` to `r`. We add `6` to the result, and push `l` then push and immediately pop `r` and recurse into it.

On the third step of recursion we are called with `Branch(Leaf,7,Leaf)`, we add `7` to our result, and push left and right `Leaf` to our stack.

On the fourth step, we peek the `Leaf` node, and finally get into the first case, where we look into the stack, and if it is not empty, then we recurse into the top. In our case the stack contains our sibling left `Leaf`, then the left sibling of the parent node, etc.

You can do the same using the OCaml toplevel, e.g.,

```
#trace tree_traverse;;
tree_traverse (t,[],prim,seco);;
```

Use the definitions of the helper function, as I provided above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped me alot.                                                                         I just figured out by your help and by looking at the algorithm it must be pre-order depth firt traversal of the given example. But how would the individual steps look like if we used my tree as an example?

Comment: I've shown the first 4 steps, and I hope that that would be enough for you to catch the pattern ;) My suggestion would be also to write this function in the `ocaml` toplevel (aka interpreter) and use the `#trace` directive, e.g., `#trace tree_traversal`, that will show all steps.

Comment: Thanks! But I am not sure how to try the function, what should I write inside tree_traverse (peek mem, pop mem, prim, seco);;

Comment: just copy paste the definitions of the helper functions that I've provided, then add definitions of the tree type, the traverse function itself, and the exemplary tree. And you're good to go. I updated the post to show how to call the function and how to enable tracing.